# Unexpected Error when using JSon URL input in spoon

Tags: json, pentaho, kettle, pdi, pentaho-spoon

I am trying to import a json in spoon. It works just fine with a file .json but when I try it from a URL I get the Unexpected Error, followed by the java null pointer exception, when executing the transformation.

I get the same error with "JSON input", and with "Get content" followed by "extract from stream" which seems to be very alike.

For the simple test I used for URL :
http://echo.jsontest.com/name/James/age/25

I tried with the "Json INPUT", selected the checkbox field as an URL, tried with the URL above (with and without the http://). And in the fields parametre I used the same ones that worked well with a file input (instead of URL).
So the JSONPATH are $.name and $.age

I also tried starting from the sample data "Json input - read incoming stream" and switching it to URL like it was described in this post :
http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?135741-Issues-with-JSON-Input-step

I am working on a distant server running on debian (jessie version).
I use pentaho 6.1

I feel like I've tried everything but I might be missing something obvious.

I apologize for my poor level of english. If more information is needed just ask. Thank you.

Comment: I switched URL because this oen was encoded in windows-1252 and I was afraid it was going to cause some trouble. I passed in the HTTP client a new URL and i get :
Unable to get result from specified URL : http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=LannionAPPID=038384d868fd92409b28d472704dbf5f
followed by host parametre is null. PLease help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started it all over again. It works now I have no idea why though.